# php array_key_exists never true

Tags: php

i am having a user input a username and having it compared to a existing file od saved usernames.
for some reason i never get a true result(i have the not true disabled to try debug)

here is the php section i am dealing with..

```
if (count($_POST))
{
$username = $_POST['username'];
$accessData = file('[path to users txt file].txt', 
FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
print_r($accessData);
print_r($username);
    if (array_key_exists($username, $accessData)) {
        header("Location: /[got page 1].html");
    } else {
        //echo "Invalid Username";
        //header("Location: /goto page 2].php");
    }
}

?>
```

so from the 2 print_r i get(test values)..

```
Array ( [0] => 1111111 [1] => 2222222 [2] => 3333333 [3] => 4444444 [4] => 55555555 ) 2222222
```

the value after the last element(2222222) is the username that was inputted.
so why do i never get a true condidition and not get directed to page 1?

Comment: You know the `array_key_exists()` function checks if a _key_ exists, not a value, right?

Comment: Please don't modify the title by adding "solved". If an answer solved it, then consider accepting the answer. That's how the system marks it as such. I rolled it back to the original.

Answer (score 3):

`array_key_exists` is for determining if an array key exists, not if a value is in the array.

You want [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array). This `in_array` function checks if the given value exist in the array. It returns true on success or false on failure.

Comment: omg u are a angel.i am not a coder just a backyard mechanic of one.i spent all day reading on try to figure this out.thank you soo much.

Comment: so my wrong thinking using array_key_exists(combined with the if statement)  was that yes the key existed in the array but i was asking if the array = input which was alway untrue(uless the array had a single value).